# React Native: How do you drag MapView pins?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

When I try to drag a pin with draggable = true, I get the following error message: "You attempted to set key 'latitude' with value  on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen."

```
<MapView
  style={{flex: 1, width: width}}
  region={{latitude: 37.754353, longitude: -122.445202, latitudeDelta: 0.14, longitudeDelta: 0.14}}
  annotations={[{
    tintColor: color.running,
    latitude: 37.756254 ,
    longitude: -122.445545,
    draggable: true
  }]}
/>
```

Comment: Show the component code

Comment: wich library to react are you using?

Comment: Facebook's MapView.  Not Leland Richardson's